# Remove last part of string after dot from one column in a data file

Tags: python, design-patterns, awk

Maybe it's a simple question but I checked some questions and I'm not able to find a proper solution for my problem. I have a big file divided in 10 columns. In the 9th column there is string containing numbers and letters separated with dots. Something like this:

```
id.aa.xx.1.rr.2930
id.ee.yy.2.gres.1
id.ww.3232
```

What I want is to remove last part of the string after last dot. Then the output should be like this:

```
id.aa.xx.1.rr
id.ee.yy.2.gres
id.ww
```

As you can see, the strings don't have the same pattern, so I can't use a split function, and neither rsplit() in python because the last field after dots goes from 1 to 6 characters per string.

Any easy solution in python or awk?

Comment: Post full line please

Comment: What's the issue with `rsplit()`? `s.rsplit('.', 1)[0]` should work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code `line[:line.rfind('.')]`

Comment: Nice trick, it was easy to add to my python code. Very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To edit the value in the 9th column of a file, you could do something like this:

```
awk '{n=split($9,a,".");$9="";for(i=1;i<n;++i)$9=$9 sprintf("%s%s",a[i],(i<n-1?".":""))}1' file
```

Split the 9th column into the array `a` using the `.` as the delimiter. Rebuild the value by looping through the array, skipping the last element. The `1` at the end is shorthand for `{print $0}` which prints the line.

This is much easier using GNU awk:

```
gawk '{$9=gensub(/(.*)\..*$/, "\\1", 1, $9)}1' file
```

The regex pattern is greedy so all of the content up to the last `.` is captured to be used in the replacement.

Comment: The `gawk` gives wrong result for `one two three four five six seven eight id.aa.xx.1.rr.2930 nine ten`.  It gives `one two three four five six seven eight one two three four five six seven eight id.aa.xx.1.rr nine ten`. First `awk` is ok

Comment: You're right, I only tested it with one column so it worked fine for me. I was missing the "how" argument so the target was `$0`. I've edited now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In python using re module can do the trick

```
>>> x=['id.aa.xx.1.rr.2930', 'id.ee.yy.2.gres.1', 'id.ww.3232']
>>> for str in x:
...     re.sub(r"\.[^.]+$", "",str)
...
'id.aa.xx.1.rr'
'id.ee.yy.2.gres'
'id.ww'
```

Or using `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/\.[^.]+$//g' input
id.aa.xx.1.rr
id.ee.yy.2.gres
id.ww
```

Or using `grep`

```
$ grep -oP  "[\w.]+(?=\.[^.]+$)" input
id.aa.xx.1.rr
id.ee.yy.2.gres
id.ww
```

Answer (score 1):

awk way if all lines need it removing.

```
awk 'sub(/\.[^\.]+$/,"",$9)' file
```

If other lines need printing

```
awk '{sub(/\.[^\.]+$/,"",$9)}1' file
```

Comment: Nice one. Did forget you could specify what field to work on.  PS you should use `awk '{sub(/\.[^\.]+$/,"",$9)}1'` to prevent problems with lines less then 9 field that would just not be printed.)

Comment: @jotne i know thats why i put if all lines need it removing at the start of my answer :)

Comment: I still would not have used it without the brackets.  It even removes blank lines.  Same as my post `'NF--'` is better with `'{NF--}1'`

Comment: @Jotne This will not break though, it will carry on happily if the line doesn't match the `sub`, the problem with `NF--` is that that script will break and cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use bash to solve the problem:

```
echo id.aa.xx.1.rr.2930 | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev
```

Result:

id.aa.xx.1.rr

**Explanation:**

rev: reverse lines --> 0392.rr.1.xx.aa.di

cut -d. -f2- --> Remove the first field of reversed string

rev: reverse again the string to the original one

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple `awk`:

```
awk -F. -v OFS=. 'NF--' file
id.aa.xx.1.rr
id.ee.yy.2.gres
id.ww
```

It just removes the last field by decrements the field counter `NF`

---

The split used by Tom is a good solution if it should be done on field `9` only.

Comment: I previously suggested this but removed it as this only applies to a single column, whereas the OP is looking to remove the value from the 9th column of a file.

Comment: @TomFenech I see.  OP should then have posted more correct sample data. I leave it, since its correct to the question: `Remove last part of string after dot` if some google it.

Comment: I agree! That's why I made the same mistake myself :)

Comment: Sorry for inconveniences, I will try to be more specific in future occasions. But thanks for helping.

Comment: Note that if there is a blank line this will break though as NF cannot be negative.Instead it is better to use `NF&&NF--` or just `{NF--}1`

Comment: @Jidder I know.  Fixed by using `{NF--}1`

Answer (score -1):

Using rev and cut:

```
cat <filename> | rev | cut -d'.' -f'2-' | rev
```

What it does:

- Reverses the line so that the part we don't want is at the beginning
- Using cut splits the line by the dot (.) and gets all the fields starting from the second one
- Reverses the line back to normal